# Сложная зона съема значений C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть Rect с которого снимаются клики мышки,ограничен координатами якорей камеры.

```
bounds = new Rect(upLeft.transform.position.x, downRight.transform.position.y,
        downRight.transform.position.x - upLeft.transform.position.x, 
upLeft.transform.position.y - downRight.transform.position.y);

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && bounds.Contains(Input.mousePosition))
    {
            Began(Input.mousePosition);
    }
```

Как добавить в него области - исключения? Допустим надо, чтобы из этого Rect правый верхний угол, например, был неактивен правый верхний угол + неактивен был правый нижний угол.
    Думается мне, это должно как то выглядеть вот так

```
public List <Rect> AreaException;
AreaException.add(new Rect (0,0, 30,30));
AreaException.add(new Rect (50,50,30,30));
```

Но что делать дальше? Вроде как надо их перебирать foreach и как то убирать из изначального Rect координаты, принадлежащие им. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы объявил класс на основе списка, в котором описал метод проверки:

```
public class AreaExceptions : List<Rect>
{
    public bool Contains(Vector3 point)
    {
        foreach(var item in this)
        {
            if (item.Contains(point) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Ну и код будет такой:

```
bounds = new Rect(upLeft.transform.position.x, downRight.transform.position.y,
        downRight.transform.position.x - upLeft.transform.position.x, 
        upLeft.transform.position.y - downRight.transform.position.y);

var exepts = new AreaExceptions();

exepts.Add(new Rect (0,0, 30,30));
exepts.Add(new Rect (50,50,30,30));

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && bounds.Contains(Input.mousePosition) && ! exepts.Contains(Input.mousePosition))
    {
            Began(Input.mousePosition);
    }
```

Единственное - координаты нужно пересчитывать с относительно координат исходного прямоугольника

Comment: Как это пересчитать?

Comment: @Dmitrii, ну, у вас зоны исключения существуют внутри отслеживаемого прямоугольника, но координаты в исключения в предложенном мной решении указываются в абсолютных (относительно прямоугольника) координатах. `exepts.Add(new Rect (0,0, bounds.x+30,bounds.y+30));` - как-то так.

Comment: Кстати, можно расширить List<Rect>